# How to delete CI interval column in gtsummary package when displaying differences between two groups?

Tags: r, gtsummary

By default, the function add_diference() in the gtsummary R package creates three columns: Difference, 95% CI and p-value. Does anyone knows hot to delete the CI column?

I tried to access the table_styling$header to hide the columns, but it is already as "FALSE".

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `modify_column_hide()` function to hide the 95% CI. Happy Programming!

```r
library(gtsummary) 
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.5.0'

trial %>%
  select(age, marker, trt) %>%
  tbl_summary(missing = "no", by = trt) %>%
  add_difference() %>%
  modify_column_hide(ci) %>%
  as_kable() # convert to kable to display on SO
```

| **Characteristic** | **Drug A**, N = 98 | **Drug B**, N = 102 | **Difference** | **p-value** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Age | 46 (37, 59) | 48 (39, 56) | -0.44 | 0.8 |
| Marker Level (ng/mL) | 0.84 (0.24, 1.57) | 0.52 (0.19, 1.20) | 0.20 | 0.12 |

<sup>Created on 2021-10-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>